# Prompt to repeat the program if y/Y is entered; Anything else terminates program - 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I have written an 8086 assembly code that adds two single digit numbers together and prints out the result. This part works flawlessly, but I have another part of the program where I have to prompt the user to decide whether or not they want to run the program again. I also have error prompts that come up if there isn't a number between 0 and 9 entered which also works flawlessly. In my code, no matter what is entered it terminates the program and I need it to repeat if y/Y is entered. Below is my full code:

```
data    SEGMENT                         ;Program Data Segment 
Prompt1  DB     "Enter a digit between 0 and 9",13,10,"$"
Prompt2  DB     "Enter another digit between 0 and 9",13,10,"$"
Prompt3  DB     "The Result is: ","$"
Prompt4  DB     "Do you want to run the program again? (Enter y/Y if so)",13,10,"$"
Prompt5  DB     "Goodbye!",13,10,"$"
CRLF     DB       13,10,'$'
error    DB     "Please enter a valid digit",13,10,"$" 
TEN      DB     10

data    ENDS

code    SEGMENT                         ;Program Code Segment 
        ASSUME  cs:code,ds:data
start:  mov     ax,data                 ;Program Entry Point 
        mov     ds,ax

          mov dx,OFFSET Prompt1         ;Tells user to enter 1st num
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h

firstch:  mov ah,01                     ;Asks for user input 1st num
          int 21h 

          cmp al,30h                    ;Compares to 0
          jl  error1
          cmp al,39h                    ;Compares to 9
          jg  error1 

          mov ch,al
          sub ch,30h                    ;Converts ASCII value to pure number

          mov dx,OFFSET CRLF             
          mov ah,09h                      
          int 21h

          mov dx,OFFSET Prompt2         ;Tells user to enter 2nd num
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h

secondch: mov ah,01                     ;Asks for user input 2nd num
          int 21h 

          cmp al,30h                    ;Compares to 0
          jl error2
          cmp al,39h                    ;Compares to 9
          jg error2

          mov cl,al
          sub cl,30h                    ;Converts ASCII value to pure number
          add ch,cl                     ;Adds cl reg to ch
          mov al,ch                     ;Moves result to al
          mov ah,0                      ;Clears ah reg
          div TEN                       ;Divides result by 10
          mov ch,al                     ;Moves remainder to ch
          mov cl,ah                     ;Moves amount of tens to cl

          mov dx,OFFSET CRLF             
          mov ah,09h                      
          int 21h

          mov dx,OFFSET Prompt3         ;Tells user the result
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h

          mov dl,ch                     ;Moves the first digit to dl reg to print
          add dl,30h
          mov ah,02                     ;Prints first digit
          int 21h

          mov dl,cl                     ;Moves the second digit to dl reg to print
          add dl,30h
          mov ah,02                     ;Prints second digit
          int 21h

          jmp repeat

 error1:  mov dx,OFFSET CRLF             
          mov ah,09h                      
          int 21h

          mov dx,OFFSET error           ;Tells user to enter valid number
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h

          jmp firstch                   ;Moves back to 1st input section


 error2:  mov dx,OFFSET CRLF             
          mov ah,09h                      
          int 21h 

          mov dx,OFFSET error           ;Tells user to enter valid number
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h 

          jmp secondch                  ;Moves back to 2nd input section

 repeat:  mov dx,OFFSET CRLF             
          mov ah,09h                      
          int 21h

          mov dx,OFFSET Prompt4         ;Asks user if they want to run again
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h

          mov ah,01
          int 21h

          cmp al,59h                    ;Compares to "Y"
          jl start
          cmp al,79h                    ;Compares to "y"
          jg start

          mov dx,OFFSET CRLF             
          mov ah,09h                      
          int 21h

          mov dx,OFFSET Prompt5         ;Tells user goodbye
          mov ah,09h
          int 21h          


finish:   mov ah, 4Ch                   ;Call terminate function
          int 21h

code    ENDS
stack   SEGMENT stack                   ;Program Stack Segment
        DW      64 DUP (?)              ;Define stack space
stack   ENDS

        END     start                   ;Mark end and define
start
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Why are you using `jl` and `jg` when all you're interested in is if `al` is exactly `'y'` or `'Y'`? (btw, just write `'Y'` instead of `59h`).

Comment: @Michael, I couldn't get any other conditional jumps to work and that's the last set I tried. What would you recommend doing to fix this issue?

Comment: `je` seems like the perfect instruction, since equality is what you're interested in, not whether the value is less than or greater anything.